# Consider dataframe records from particular records to particular records in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

by considering existing datafarame records, i want to get the records from particular hp source records to before particular hp source records like below mentioned output result.

Here is the example df:

```
seq_id       file_name      source       date

b21345350    a.txt          ad          2022-04-15
b32145660    e.txt          qe          2022-04-15
c43526890    ace.txt        hp          2022-04-15
re2345566    wer.csv        hp          2022-04-15
b43251044    op.xlsx        fa          2022-04-15
b6512400     ip.csv         jm          2022-04-15
b9123420     tb.xlsx        tp          2022-04-15
b3214563     cv.txt         ux          2022-04-14
b45678900    em.txt         hp          2022-04-14
b65357023    rt.csv         hp          2022-04-14
b90879081    ty.txt         mp          2022-04-14
b19019019    sd.txt         jp          2022-04-14
```

But i want to create the result dataframe from hp source to before hp source records like below output result :

```
seq_id        file_name        source        date

c43526890    ace.txt        hp          2022-04-15
re2345566    wer.csv        hp          2022-04-15
b43251044    op.xlsx        fa          2022-04-15
b6512400     ip.csv         jm          2022-04-15
b9123420     tb.xlsx        tp          2022-04-15
b3214563     cv.txt         ux          2022-04-14
```

can anyone help me to get the above result dataframe.

Comment: You need more details on your inputs. What does "considering datafarame records from particular date and sourcename to particular date and sourcename" even mean?

Comment: @ifly6, actually there is existed dataframe. by using that existing dataframe, i want to get the required result as another dataframe like above mentioned output result

Comment: So that in no way explains what you are filtering your rows on or what your logic is. The only answer that could be given based on your current explanation is something like `def output(the_input): return prespecified_output`.

Comment: Sorry this explanation is very much unclear. My best guess is that you want to *get all **intermediate rows** between **rows with** `df['source']=='hp'`, but also the **first consecutive rows** that satisfy this particular condition*. Is this correct? If so, please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df['source'].eq('hp')
g = (s.ne(s.shift()) & s).cumsum()
d = {i:j for i,j in df.loc[g.ne(0)].groupby(g)}
```

After you have created the dictionary, you can pull the first group by using the code below:

```
d.get(1)
```

Output:

```
      seq_id file_name source        date
2  c43526890   ace.txt     hp  2022-04-15
3  re2345566   wer.csv     hp  2022-04-15
4  b43251044   op.xlsx     fa  2022-04-15
5   b6512400    ip.csv     jm  2022-04-15
6   b9123420   tb.xlsx     tp  2022-04-15
7   b3214563    cv.txt     ux  2022-04-14
```

Comment: Can we achieve the same thing with sql code

Comment: Is it possible to achieve on the same with sql code? if possible please let me know .